# How to send Gmail talk messages using Gmails built it method

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I want to create a Google Chrome extension that, among other things, will modify the chat text based on what is inputed. I will add a button next to the video, call, and add people buttons below the name, and when clicked will activate the modifications. I don't want to have to put any more scripts on the page than I have to, so I would like to be able to send the messages the way Gmail would be pressing "return" in the chat box. Also I want to to be able to show that both of the people chatting are using my extension by displaying text in the chat box just like the "This chat is off the record" text is, and possibly if both are using it add extra stuff to the chat. What I tried to do was make an imitation textarea and when the user 'sends' it, grab it and modify it, then insert it into the real one and send the new text. I can change the text but can't seem to send it...

Heres what I have so far, I enclosed everything in a setInterval to check if chat box exists and add appropriate stuff to it:

```
var chatBtnClone = setInterval(function() {
    if ($("body").find(".nH .NG").length > 0) {  //if chat is active

        var clone = $("body").find(".nH .NG .NJ").first();
        if (clone.children()[0].className.indexOf("chat") < 0) { //if already added my class
            var clonned = clone.clone();
            var clonnedChd = clonned.children().first();
            clonnedChd.attr("title", "Start encrypted chat");
            clonnedChd.on('click', function() {
                console.log("clicked chatBtn!"); //make sure it works
                var self = $(this);
                if (self[0].className.indexOf("chatEncX") >= 0) { //toggle button pic 
                    self.removeClass('chatEncX').addClass('chatEnc');
                    self.attr("title", "Stop encrypted chat");
                } else {
                    self.removeClass('chatEnc').addClass('chatEncX');
                    self.attr("title", "Start encrypted chat");
                }
            });
            clone.parent().prepend(clonned);
            clonned.find('.NK').removeClass("NK-Y8").addClass("chatEncX");
        }

        var chatBoxs = $('body').find(".nn .AD");
        var chatArea = chatBoxs.first().find(".nH textarea"); //get chat textareas
        if (chatArea.length === 1) {
            var clonChatArea = chatArea.first().clone();
            clonChatArea.removeAttr("id");
            chatArea.first().parent().append(clonChatArea);
            // chatArea.first().hide();
            var chatTextDiv = chatBoxs.first().find(".jp .nH .nH").first();
            clonChatArea.focusin(function() {
                chatTextDiv.removeClass("gv").addClass("f7");
            });
            clonChatArea.focusout(function() {
                chatTextDiv.removeClass("f7").addClass("gv");
            });
            clonChatArea.on('keyup', function(event) {
                var self = this;
                //console.log(this.style.height); //make sure height it working

                if (self.scrollHeight === 38) {
                    self.style.overflowY = "hidden";
                    self.style.height = "36px";
                } else if (self.scrollHeight === 47) {
                    self.style.height = "54px";
                } else if (self.scrollHeight === 62) {
                    self.style.height = "72px";
                } else if (self.scrollHeight >= 77) {
                    self.style.height = "80px";
                    self.style.overflowY = "scroll";
                }

                if( event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey ){
                    //regular, just insert a newline
                } else if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    //grab text and modify then reinsert into real textarea
                    var chatTxt = $(this).val();
                    var chatHidden = chatBoxs.first().find(".nH textarea").first();
                    var chatEncTxt = Crypto.AES.encrypt(chatTxt, "pass"); //modify text
                    //console.log(chatEncTxt);
                    chatHidden.val(chatEncTxt);
                    chatHidden.focus();
                    chatHidden.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 13 }); //try to imitate the return key and send (NOT WORKING!!!)
                    // $(this).focus();
                }
            });
        }
    }
},150);
```

Comment: Yes, I found out Gmail uses [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) for the chat. And i'v looked through Gmails's scripts, but they are just too confusing to make any use of. I tried mimicking the "return" key to send the message, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: In order that we can help you, please show how far you have got already, a specific problem you are facing, as well as a snippet of code to show what you are attempting. Welcome to StackOverflow :) Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you want to see how to ask good questions.

Comment: OK, thank you for the advice. I edited my original question with a bit more clarification and change to my extension that more or less does the same thing. I also added code snippets of what I have already.

Comment: You could also try to reverse engineer the JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit late, but if anyone else is interested then I managed this by doing the following:

```
var e = new Event("keypress");
e.keyCode = e.which = 13;
// :mc is an example textarea id, but the OP has the code for finding that already
document.getElementById(':mc').dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: That would probably work, but since I asked the question, quite a bit changed in Gmail. Like now the chats are in iframes and aren't even textareas and as such, I can't find the node that actually handles the event and so I can't tell if this works or not.

Comment: I too have been working on that! That code will still work for the <div> that is used for gmail now. However you will now need to load your script in each iframe